# YARPP php question

Tags: posts, css

I'm trying to put a border under `related_posts()` ,it works, but the border is showing even when the there are no posts. How do I make the border show only when there are related posts to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the border using CSS? If so, you should set "Default display if no results:" under Settings to nothing. If that is nothing, YARPP will show nothing.